# Flutter giving me massive migraine : "positional arguments must occur before named arguments"

Tags: flutter

Throws error @ Scaffold saying too many positional arguments, and another @ Padding saying positional arguments must occur before named arguments.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() =>
    runApp(MaterialApp
    (debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     home: LoginScreen()
     )
    );

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
            child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                height: 260,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/RightLogo.jpg"),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill))),
            Positioned(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Login",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             Container(
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: Colors.white,
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                 boxShadow: [
                   BoxShadow(
                     color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .8),
                     blurRadius: 20.0,
                     offset: Offset(0, 10)
                   )
                 ]
               ),
               child: Column(
                 children: <Widget>[
                   Container(
                     padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[100]))
                     ),
                     child: TextField(
                       decoration: InputDecoration(
                         border: InputBorder.none,
                         hintText: "User Name/Login",
                         hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400])
                       ),
                     )
                   ),
                    Container(
                     padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                     child: TextField(
                       decoration: InputDecoration(
                         border: InputBorder.none,
                         hintText: "Password",
                         hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400])
                       ),
                     )
                   )
                 ],
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 30,),
             Container(
               height: 50,
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                 gradient: LinearGradient(
                   colors: [
                     Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, 1),
                     Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .6),
                   ]
                )
               ),
             )
        ])
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

So what's the reason? I know its a mistake by me but I'd appreciate it if someone pointed out the flaw. Also the rest of the code is probably useless.

Edited after comment about missing code. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Formatting your code would help a lot to see that kind of mistakes. Your code in the question is incorrect. Some part of it is missing.

Comment: Done. Put the rest of the code, thought it would be useless. Sorry.

Comment: Yes actually your idea is great. You should not put uncessary code but also try not to put missing code. I could not compile your code because of missing parantheses and the rest. When you are removing the unnecessary code try to make it without harming the other parts. Welcome to stackoverflow btw. :)

Comment: Many thanks. Really appreciate all the help <3

Comment: And thank you! I feel at home.

Comment: Your code is badly structured, you might need to go back and read the docs about Scaffold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your padding is not inside of your column widget's children list. It is used as a positional argument to scaffold.

Simply ctrl + x your padding and paste it into column's children.

```
Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                height: 260,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/RightLogo.jpg"),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill))),
            Positioned(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Login",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .8),
                              blurRadius: 20.0,
                              offset: Offset(0, 10))
                        ]),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                    bottom:
                                        BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[100]))),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: "User Name/Login",
                                  hintStyle:
                                      TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400])),
                            )),
                        Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: "Password",
                                  hintStyle:
                                      TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400])),
                            ))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                          Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, 1),
                          Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .6),
                        ])),
                  )
                ])),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Ahaaaa, alright. Now I understand. Now a serious question, how to fix that? Forgive me but I'm new to flutter and a total noob‍♂️

Comment: I have edited the answer. If you are a complete beginner you can buy Maximilian Schwarzmuller's flutter course. It is a great source to learn it from scratch. It is for beginners and it is really perfect.

Comment: OMG you guys are so nice! Thank you a million times <3